# Extracting people names from emails

Tags: sql, postgresql, email

I have a big table with only one row containing email addresses and I need to get people's names from emails where it is possible. For example, from the mail daniela.meyer@example.de I need to get a name (daniela) and a surname (meyer).
I think I need table with people names and compare each email with this database. But I can't understand what is the correct way of doing such a comparison ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is extract user's name from email ADDRESS, not email content?

Comment: don't confuse database with tables. give sample table you have

Comment: Yes, I have just email addresses

Comment: So if you want to get the names you could split the String at "@" and "." and hope that the users used firstname.lastname@provider as syntax for their mails, but I think that is unrealistic tbh. You can not validate if that is a "correct" name or not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(emailaddress, CHARINDEX('@', emailaddress) - 1)
```

It seeks the position of the @, and takes the number of characters up to but not including (that's the - 1) the @ symbol.

Be careful with strings that don't have an @ though; you'll end up an empty string.

I didn't fully understand if you have the data in different databases or in different tables. I also don't know in which sql language do you want.

Luck,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(email_column_name,0, CHARINDEX('@',email_column_name)) FROM table_name
```

But you **can't validate it as a name**.

**Updated Answer:** If you wan't to **ignore numbers** in the email address, try `REPLACE`

```
SELECT REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (SUBSTRING(email_column_name,0, CHARINDEX('@',email_column_name)), '0', ''),
'1', ''),
'2', ''),
'3', ''),
'4', ''),
'5', ''),
'6', ''),
'7', ''),
'8', ''),
'9', '') FROM table_name
```

**Note:** works perfectly in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use split_part to get the elements of a delimited string:

```
select split_part(split_part(email, '@', 1), '.', 1) as firstname, 
       split_part(split_part(email, '@', 1), '.', 2) as lastname
from the_table;
```

The inner `split_part()` will extract the part before the `@` and the outer `split_part()` then gets the first and second element from that.

---

Note that you can't validate that the email is **really** structured that way. `dent.arthur@h2gc.com` would result in `dent` as the firstname and `arthur` as the lastname.